# angular Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>

Tags: angular

I am getting two errors in my code and dont know how i can solve it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'app/services/api/api.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as moment from 'moment';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Component({
 selector: 'app-invites',
 templateUrl: './invites.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./invites.component.scss'],

   })
 export class InvitesComponent implements OnInit {
 clientData: Observable<any>;
 data: any  = []; 
     cities:Set = new Set();
           url:any;



constructor(private api:ApiService,private modalService: NgbModal,private router:Router, public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { 

          this.getClaims();

   }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 userFilter: any = { city: '', name: ''};


getClaims(){

    this.url = 'url.com';

        this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url,{responseType: 'json'}).
           subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data);

           this.data = data.records;
           this.data.forEach(d => this.cities.add(d.city));
       });
     }

  }
```

1)error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
2)Generic type 'Set' requires 1 type argument(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As described in the error message, you are assigning a subscribtion `this.http.get(...).subscribe()` to clientData, which is of type `Observable<any>`

```
clientData: Subscription
```

is the right type here.

2) In typescript, you need to type the arguments which will be passed to your Set :

```
cities: Set<type of your city here>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a bit of confusion setting your types there

in your code you're saying that `clientData` is an `Observable<any>`, but, when you   call your `getClaims` method

```
getClaims() {

       this.url = 'url.com';

       // here is an observable
       this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url, {responseType: 'json'}); 

       // here it becomes a Subscription
       this.clientData = this.clientData.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);

            this.data = data.records;
            this.data.forEach(d => this.cities.add(d.city));
        });
    }
```

for your `Set` you need a type hint, like you did for `Observable<any>`, so it would become

```
cities: Set<another type here>
```

Side note: please cover your API url as it actually shows something